# JavaScript : Hosting User Images in S3 Bucket For Application

Tags: javascript, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

The "**Background**" outlines the problem in depth- **I added it to make this question a good guide for using S3 to host images(like a profile image)**

You can skip right to "**HERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE**" to help directly.

-----------------------------------------------**Background**------------------------------------------------------------------ 
**Note: Feel Free to Critique My Assumptions on how to Host Images Properly for future readers.**

So for a quick prototype- I'm hosting user avatar images in an AWS S3 Bucket,but **I want to model roughly how it is done in production.**

Here are **my 3 assumptions on how to model industry standard image hosting**.(based off sites I've studied):

1. **For Reading** - you can use public endpoints(no tokens needed)
2. **To Secure Reading Access** - use hashing to store the resources(image).The application will give the hashed URL to users with access.

   For Example 2 hashes (1 for file path and 1 for image):
   https://myapp.com/images/1024523452345233232000/f567457645674242455c32cbc7.jpg

   ^The above can be done with S3 using a hashed "Prefix" and a hashed file name.
3. **Write Permissions** - The user should be logged into the app and be given temp credentials to write to the storage(ie add an image).

*So with those 3 assumptions this is what I'm doing and the problem:*

(A Simple Write - Use Credentials)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AWS.config.credentials = ...;
  AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'}});
  ...
  var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
      bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        //Do Something Amazing!!
  });
</script>
```

---------------------------------**HERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE**----------------------------------------------------------(A Simple Read -Give The User a Signed URL) **Error 403 Permissions**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      AWS.config.credentials..
      AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
      var s3 = new AWS.S3();
      var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey.jpg'};
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
            // Getting a 403 Permissions Error!!!
          });
      });
</script>
```

I figure the signed URL isn't needed, but I thought it would get me around the permission error but **I have to set the permission manually to public to read the image.**

QUESTION:

- **So how should I make the endpoints completely public(read-able) for those who have gained access to the URL, but only write-able when the user has credentials?**

Comment: You should not be securing using hashes instead use presigned GET url. Your files are either public-read or private. You can give access to your private objects for authenticated users using presigned URLs. If you want to allow users to upload directly to S3 from browser you can use presigned POST url.

Comment: @KrishnaSrinivas  I essentially want to make them public. I've noticed must social media apps for example, once the url is given to the user they can open it from any device(which makes me assume there is no tokens involved for access). Yet the photo themselves have hashed names.

Comment: no, apps don't use hashes for security they would use hash as file name just to make it unique. You can check the URL to a private facebook photo, you can see that there is image name which looks like a hash followed by a signature. Anyone having the image name and the signature will be able to access the image. The signature might also contain a expiry time (not sure how facebook implements it). Signature added to the URL is how generally apps secure the images or other files.

Answer (score 1):

To make an object publicly-downloadable when you are uploading it, apply the canned (predefined) ACL called "public-read" with the putObject request.

```
var params = {
  Key: file.name, 
  ContentType: file.type, 
  Body: file,
  ACL: 'public-read'
};
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: When I add **ACL: 'public-read'** to the params I now get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" when trying to write.

Comment: But you are able to successfully upload the object if you omit this?

Comment: yea it's working to upload, but what I upload I can't read(I read the way described above). I get **Error 403 Permissions**. I want anything that is written to be readable by any user publicly.(I'm using hashing to secure images).

Comment: What permissions are you granting in the bucket or IAM user policy?  If only `s3:putObject` you *may* also need `s3:putObjectAcl`. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

Comment: Under Permissions for the Bucket I set Grantee:Everyone , List:checked Upload/Delete:Checked ViewPermissions:Checked EditPermissions:Checked. Yet images uploaded can't be read by IAM user without setting the image itself to public.